# 301 Redirect pointing to a different location

Tags: wordpress, googlebot

I can browse the website https://builtsearch.com.au through browser correctly but when I use cUrl command and use googlebot as the agent I get this.

```
curl -A 'Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)' -i https://builtsearch.com.au/
```

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Date: Wed, 03 Mar 2021 02:24:42 GMT
Server: Apache
X-Powered-By: PHP/7.3.18
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Location: http://www.micaze.com/kategori/izmir-escort/
Content-Length: 0
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8**
```

This wrong 301 redirection is stopping googlebot from indexing the website.

The website is using Wordpress.

Any thoughts?

Comment: That looks like you have been hacked. Check your .htaccess file for mentions of that url. Once you have found the hack, then follow best practices to clean up after a hack and stop it happening again.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Tony McCreath. It turns out that my index.php was updated by some malicious plug-in. Sanitizing the index.php seems to resolve the issue.

Comment: Good to know. I guess you get to mark this as best answer :-)